# linux- can not find the files

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, file

I have a really strange problem:
(from the main function):

```
try {
        java.io.InputStream is = null;

        if (args.length == 0) {
            is =
            ClassLoader.
            getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("level_sets.txt");
        } else {
            is =
            ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(args[0]);
        }
    LineNumberReader reader = null;
    reader = new LineNumberReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    LevelSetReader lsr = new LevelSetReader(reader);
    List<String> keyAdderss = lsr.getKeyAdressMap();
    for (int i = 0; i < keyAdderss.size(); i++) {
        String add = keyAdderss.get(i);
        File file = new File(add);
        BufferedReader reader2 = null;
        try {
            reader2 = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(
                                new FileInputStream(file)));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

the progrem at first check if there is a single commandline paramete - if don't, go to our default file called: "level_set.txt"(in our bin) otherwise check the file there.
(The level_sets.txt file contein addresses to other txt files.)
After that call every address and analise those too...
The problem is that he can no find those files in linux...
He can find  the level_sets.txt but not the other files...

I must mention that it works perfect in eclips!
We tried hundreds of way but failed...

In addition, when we deleted the if-else at the begining it worked!!!
like:

```
java.io.InputStream is = null;
    is =
    ClassLoader.
    getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("level_sets.txt");
```

What to do?
Thanks! :)

Comment: try {
            reader2 = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(
                                new FileInputStream(file)));

Comment: `level_sets.txt` or `level_set.txt`? Or `set_level`? You're inconsistent in your question. Also, how are your classes packaged up? If you're using a jar file, then the *directory* won't be on the class path...

Comment: yes I do use a jar file!
How can i do that the directry will be on the class path?

Comment: You can't use FileInputStream if it's in a jar file. Where in the jar is the text file? Which class in the jar is trying to load it (it's full name, don't just reply "the main class")?

Comment: 1.level_sets.txt - is in the bin
all the others are in a reasources folder.
2. the class LevelSetReader trying to load the file!
Thanks!